# Representing percentages up to and including 100% in MySQL

Tags: mysql, percentage

I have a table in my database that represents the similarity between two things. Some thing like:

```
+------------+------+
| Field      | Type |
+------------+------+
| id_a       | int  |
| id_b       | int  |
| similarity | ???  |
+------------+------+
```

`similarity` will hold the degree of similarity between `id_a` and `id_b` in percent, and can range from 100% similar (identical things) down to *but not including* 0%. I won't be storing links for things which are 0% similar (i.e. completely different). In other words I need to store the range `[100, 0)`. The amount of decimal places isn't terribly important, but 1 or 2 would be nice.

The solution I've typically seen suggested is to use something like `decimal(4,2)`. The problem with that for my use case is that it stores `(100,0]`.

I've come up with two possible solutions, both using `decimal(4,2)`, but they both seem like hacks:

### option 1

Store `similarity - 0.01` and add the `0.01` back when retrieving it. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO similarities (id_a, id_b, similarity) VALUES (1, 2, ? - 0.01);
```

And then:

```
SELECT id_a, id_b, similarity + 0.01 FROM similarities;
```

### option 2

Store percent differences from 0%-99.99%, and then convert to similarity when retrieving:

```
SELECT id_a, id_b, 100 - difference AS similarity FROM similarities;
```

In both cases I would probably create a view using `MERGE`, rather than leaving the addition and subtraction in the queries.

Are there any better options than these? If there aren't, which would you choose and why?

#### note:

I don't mind using some other representation, like `[1,0)`, as long as it represents the range well.

#### Edit to clarify:

Inserts are done rarely, and are only done by me, not users, and are done in large batches. I know that the data I'm inserting will always be in [100,0), so it's not a question of enforcement, but rather of what the most efficient/natural representation is

Comment: Why does this enforcement need to in the form of a column type?  Why not just store the data as is and set a trigger to enforce this?

Comment: Basically, inserts are done rarely, and are only done by me, not users, and are done in large batches. I know that the data I'm inserting will always be in `[100,0)`, so it's not a question of enforcement, but rather of what the most efficient/natural representation is.

Comment: `decimal(5,2)` would be the right choice for this.

Comment: It's *always* a question of enforcement.

Comment: @Catcall - can you expand on that? I'm not certain what you mean.

Comment: It means that, as sure as the sun will rise again tomorrow, someday you'll enter a value that's outside the range [100,0). That's why foreign keys, check constraints, and "create domain" statements exist in SQL. They exist so the ever watchful eye of the dbms can guard against bad data, and so you can relax just a little.

Comment: Why not us an unsigned int storing the range `[10000,0)` and divide by 100 to get what you´re after? int is fairly efficient storing and using for hacks? (Even though i agree `double(5,2)` is the ´right´ from an sql-perspective, but leading to some more overhead)

Comment: Because values in the range 0-10000 violate [the principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). And you have to remember to divide by 100 every time you use it.  We all have enough to remember without things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a dbms that complies with SQL standards, you would declare the column to be of type decimal(5, 2) (or use the equivalent decimal fraction), and use a CHECK constraint to limit the range.

```
create table data (
  id integer primary key,
  pct decimal(5, 2) not null check (pct > 0 and pct <= 100)
);
```

But MySQL doesn't comply with SQL standards. It doesn't enforce CHECK constraints.  So I think you have two choices.

1. Write a trigger to check the range, and rollback inserts and updates
   that fall outside your chosen range.
2. Use a foreign key reference to a table of valid values. In your
   case, that table would only have 10,000 rows, right?

If I needed to use the percentage in further calculations, I'd much prefer values in the range of .0001 to 1.0000, so they could be used directly. It doesn't look like that's a concern in your application, though.

Comment: I made an edit to my question to clarify it, my concern is more about efficiency than about enforcing my range, as I will be the only one doing inserts to this table.

Comment: After some thought I think you're right on all counts (`decimal(5,2)`, storing `[1,0)` rather than `[100,0)`, and adding a trigger for peace of mind). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the similarity as a percentage, per sè, give them similarity-scores in the range `[1,10000]` (or `(0,10000]` if you like). That gives you 100 points per percentage-point (efficiently two decimals if you need).

Storage: `int(32)`

View: `SELECT id_a, id_b, similarity/100 FROM similarities;`